# Windows inventory using python

Tags: python, window, inventory, os.system, exitstatus

Am trying to create inventory report for set of windows servers using following function. But, this function always fails ping test for all hosts, though am apple to ping a few of them cleanly from command line.
tried multiple combination, not able to figure out what is limiting it from hitting ping pass block ?
please suggest,

```
def StartInvetoryCollection() :
    for eachline in open('HostList.txt', 'r') :
        RemoteHost = eachline.strip()
        print(RemoteHost, end='')
        if os.system('ping RemoteHost -c 4') == 0 :
            print('\t\tPING=PASS',end='')
            ReportFileName = RemoteHost + '_msinfo.txt'
            os.system('msinfo32 /computer Host /report ReportFileName')
            print('\tData Collection=PASS')
        else :
            print('\t\tPING=FAIL\tData Collection=SKIP')
            pass
```

Hostlist.txt - contains one hostname per line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass your value into the `os.system`:

```
def StartInvetoryCollection() :
    for eachline in open('HostList.txt', 'r') :
        RemoteHost = eachline.strip()
        print(RemoteHost, end='')
        if os.system('ping {} -n 4'.format(RemoteHost)) == 0 :
            print('\t\tPING=PASS',end='')
            ReportFileName = RemoteHost + '_msinfo.txt'
            os.system('msinfo32 /computer Host /report {}'.format(ReportFileName))
            print('\tData Collection=PASS')
        else :
            print('\t\tPING=FAIL\tData Collection=SKIP')
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks fo your response Tony.D !, But this is also not going to pass section. I kept only 'localhost' in hostname.txt, but ping reported failed for localhost as well.

Comment: **Thanks Tiny.D !**, Working now. But what if i want to include command flags as well.

Comment: you have to make sure your command flags are supported by your host.

Comment: if it is windows host, the flag should be `n` instead of `c`